# How can I call a WordPress shortcode in specific template

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

I use Simple Blog Stats WordPress plugin and I want to show numbers of users. Simple Blog Stats WordPress plugin has a shortcode [sbs_users]. But I want to show it on specific template - search_paralex_2.php and I can't use shortcode here. I try

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[user_count]');  ?>
```

But I get result - [user_count]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try this ?

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[sbs_users]');  ?>
```

The shortcode you write in your example is `[user_count]`